# Is solar panel efficiency defined and measured differently for space vs terrestrial applications?

Tags: artificial-satellite, solar-power

Since *the shape* (as well as the integral) of the [solar irradiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_irradiance) spectrum above the atmosphere is different than that below it, is the efficiency of photovoltaic solar panels defined and measured differently than those for terrestrial applications?

In the related question [Why are these multi-junction solar cells 40% efficient on earth but 30% in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17784/12102) some of the issues mentioned there are related to ratings - which are likely to be conservative lower limits. Here I'm asking about the *definition of efficiency and its testing procedure* and how it may differ when applied to panels destined for space and terrestrial applications.

[image]

**above:** Solar spectrum [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_mass_(solar_energy)#/media/File:Solar_Spectrum.png).

Answer (score -1):

It's based on an approximation of the photon flux (number of photons impinging on the surface per time). I do not know of any reason to differentiate the ground and orbit environments otherwise. I do not know of any efficiency difference. This does not come from a builder, but a user. We need a canonical answer from a builder. ;)