# What is the material and reflectivity of the surface of Parker Solar Probe's heat shield that faces the Sun?

Tags: heat-shield, parker-solar-probe

The Parker Solar probe will launch soon, and over a period of years and several planetary flyby's loose enough energy from its heliocentric orbit to reach an orbit with a perhihelion of only about 4 million km.

The Spacecoast Daily article [Traveling to the Sun: NASA Describes ‘Why Parker Solar Probe Won’t Melt?’](http://spacecoastdaily.com/2018/07/traveling-to-the-sun-nasa-describes-why-parker-solar-probe-wont-melt/) links to the video [Blowtorch vs Heat Shield](https://youtu.be/BKinVmBoIrE) which shows only dark carbon-like materials, but in the video [Why Won't it Melt? How NASA's Solar Probe will Survive the Sun](https://youtu.be/TN6rZF5dSRg) the surface of the heat shield is white, as it is in the photo below.

What material will make up the surface of Parker's heat shield that faces the sun, and what is its reflectivity in visible and near IR wavelengths where most of the Sun's intensity falls?

The caption for the image from [here](http://spacecoastdaily.com/2018/07/traveling-to-the-sun-nasa-describes-why-parker-solar-probe-wont-melt/) says:

> Parker Solar Probe’s heat shield is made of two panels of superheated carbon-carbon composite sandwiching a lightweight 4.5-inch-thick carbon foam core. To reflect as much of the Sun’s energy away from the spacecraft as possible, the Sun-facing side of the heat shield is also sprayed with a **specially formulated white coating**. (NASA Image)

More about the heat shield in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17500/12102).

[image: Parker Solar Probe heat shield]

Comment: I was planning on asking this exact question today!

Comment: @Jack "[d'oh!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnaeIAEp2pU)" Sorry about that!

Comment: No not at all! I’m interested to see some answers

Comment: Unobtainium, of course!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was difficult to answer until I figured out that this mission used to be called "Solar Probe Plus" and all the early studies were done under that name.

From [here](https://solarprobe.gsfc.nasa.gov/SolarProbe+ME.pdf):

> As  part  of  the  TPS  Risk  Mitigation  effort,   two potential
>   ceramic coatings were found that  met the requirements of the Solar
>   Probe+ mission.  Ceramic  materials  that  are  visibly  white
>   generally  provide  the  optical  characteristics   compatible  with 
>   the  proposed  shield  passive   thermal  management  strategy. 
>   These  characteristics are low solar absorptivity and high IR 
>   emissivity.    Thermodynamic    stability    and     chemical 
>   compatibility  with  C-C  are  additional  differentiators  that 
>   further  narrow  the   list  of  candidate  ceramics.  At  the  end 
>   of  the   study,  both  aluminum  oxide  (Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>),  commonly 
>   called  alumina,  and  pyrolytic  boron   nitride (PBN) were found to
>   notionally satisfy  these basic characteristics.

Annoyingly this paper doesn't say which of the two was chosen. It does touch on the optical properties though:

> The   key  optical  property  is  the  ratio   of  the  solar  absorptance  to  the  IR  emissivity,   α / ε ,  set  at  the   design
>   value of 0.6 in Figure 3.6-1, which shows  that  the  shield 
>   temperatures  are  reduced  as  the   Sun  distance  increases  or 
>   the  cone  angle  is  decreased.

[image]

Happily, this [one](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3001&context=physics_facpub) does:

> The  baseline  coating  for  the  Solar  Probe  primary  shield 
>   (without  modifications  such  as  doping)  is  a  thin   (100 − 125 
>   μm)  coating  of  alumina  (Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>)  on  a  C-C  composite.

Some articles about the mission state that this coating was applied via plasma spray, this [news article](http://kennedalenews.com/local-business-providing-major-component-for-nasas-parker-solar-probe-p6363-196.htm) appears to confirm that.

> The white coating on the front of the heat shield, the part that will
>   face the Sun, was sprayed on by Plasma Processes, Inc. in Huntsville,
>   Alabama.

Comment: Oh of course! I had a brief search earlier, but forgot about the name change so came up empty handed! Great answer

Comment: Very nice detective work, and very concisely written and well-sourced as well. Thanks!

Comment: The first linked reference is a pretty comprehensive one, although from rather early in the design process.