# How deep into the corona could the Parker Solar Probe go without being damaged?

Tags: the-sun, heat, parker-solar-probe, corona

An answer to the question [Has any object launched from Earth gone into the Sun?](http://Has%20any%20object%20launched%20from%20Earth%20gone%20into%20the%20Sun?) says

> The probe will repeatedly touch the outer corona until mission end in 2025, with the closest approach being 3.83 million miles.

Could the probe go any lower into the corona for a short period of time, similar to the duration the probe will be doing in its orbit, and remain in the same operating condition?

Comment: related: [At what distance to the sun would the Parker Solar Probe completely fail?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33111/12102) and [How is Parker Solar Probe so robust against coronal mass ejections?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40392/12102) and [How does the Parker Solar Probe's heat shield protect it from dust near the sun?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17562/12102)

Comment: Remember that the Sun and its corona is huge. The Parker solar probe is on an elliptical orbit around the Sun, it could not go any lower into the corona for a short period of time. If the probe changes its orbit to go deeper into the corona, it will stay there for a long time. Going deeper for a short time and back up again will need a huge amount of fuel.

Comment: @Uwe Thanks, I understand. I'm not concern with the orbital dynamics and the necessary delta-v. I'm just curious about how well the probe would survive.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Any closer, the sun would peek around the edges of the probe's shield, like an annular eclipse, and fry some of its parts.  Almost a duplicate question: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38657/1235

Answer (score -4):

The Sun's corona extends for millions of miles. The Sun's corona is much hotter (by a factor from 150 to 450x) than the visible surface of the Sun: the photosphere's average temperature is 5800 kelvin compared to the corona's one to three million kelvin. Never the less he corona is a trillion times less particle density. The parker probe will by 11 million miles from the Sun. Without it's current solar shield the probe would last 10 seconds. So a million miles closer it'd probably melt or incinerate.

Comment: Why mention 11 million when we're considering 3.83 million?  Also, where did the figure of 10 seconds come from?